# Как проверить помещаеться слово или нет в таблицу?

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Столкнулся с спроблемой. Не могу понять как мне слово которое я разложил по буквам и где у меня есть таблица 10х10 с рандомными буквами. Как мне правильно написать проверку для слова которое я хочу поместить в таблицу?

```
string searchWord = "House";
char [] charArr = searchWord.ToCharArray();
int arrLength = charArr.Length;
Console.Write("Die Länge vom string" + arrLength + " ");






string [,] Grid = new string [10,10];
string [] randomLetter = new string [26] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
Random rng = new Random();

for(int x = 0; x < Grid.GetLength(0); x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < Grid.GetLength(1); y++){
    
        int nextRandom = rng.Next(0, 26);
        Console.Write("Index of Char (random)" + nextRandom);
        string actualRandomLetter = randomLetter[nextRandom];
        Grid[x,y] = actualRandomLetter; 
        Console.Write(Grid);
            
    
}
```

[image: Сама таблица]

### **АПДЕЙТ Вопроса!!!**

```
    public static void GetTheChar ()
{
    string word = "House";
    char[] searchWord = word.ToCharArray();


    int row = 10;
    int  col = 10;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    var randomRowIndex = rnd.Next(0, 9);
    var randomRow = randomRowIndex;
    var randomCol = rnd.Next(0, 9);


    for (int start = randomCol, index = 0; index < searchWord.Length && start < randomRow; ++start, ++index)
    {
        randomRow = randomRowIndex;
        randomRowIndex = searchWord[start];
    }
```

Написал код который должен был работать и вставлять слово на рандомное место и проверять подходит слово по длинне или нет. Но где то я накосяичл и не могу понять где  у меня в коде ошибка

Comment: Столкнулся с *спроблемой*. Не могу понять ваш вопрос...

Comment: а какую проверку чего именно необходимо написать?

Comment: Извиняюсь, попробую простым русским, как мне поместить слово **House** в свою таблицу ?

Comment: Все просто - выбрасываете 5 букв из таблицы и вставляете свои буквы, вставлять можете как душе угодно.

Comment: @Dima Что-то яснее не стало от вашего объяснения. Проверка то в чём заключается?

Comment: Может проблема и заключается в том что вы не можете объяснить, что же вы хотите на самом деле?

Comment: Я наверно не правильно выразился. У меня есть слово **House** который я разобрал по буквам и сохранил в новой перемнной char [] newString. Как мне теперь это слово засунуть в таблицу ?

Comment: @Dima А по какому принципу заполняется таблица? Вам в произвольное место таблицы это слово нужно поместить? Ничего непонятно.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, думал что бы рандомно выбрался индекс от таблицы и поставил туда первую букву от слова, и потом следовала проверка помещаеться все слово в таблицу горизонтально или нет

Comment: тогда вам не надо было разбирать слово на символы. Ширина таблицы - 10. Находите длину слова, прибавляете к вашему рандомному индексу по столбцам - если получилось меньше или равно 10 - значит влезет, если больше - не влезет.

Comment: @DmitryK не могли бы вы примеров написать??

Comment: Получаете рандомный индекс, например - `3`. Получаете длину слова `House` - `5`. `3+5 < 10` - значит слово влезет в строку. Или от обратного: чтобы слово влезло в строку, индекс не должен превышать значения `ширина строки` - `длина слова`, т.е. `10-5=5`.

Comment: `int randomIndex = rng.Next(0, Grid.GetLength(0));
        if(searchWord.Length < Grid.GetLength(0))
        {
           а что теперь нужно написать
        }`

Comment: Зачем все кому не лень это делают `searchWord.ToCharArray()`? Что вас этому учит? К строке можно же напрямую к символам обращаться точно так же как в массиве, и длина у нее есть точно такая же.

Comment: Ну напишите пример